# Set up Recovery Actions to Take Place When a Service Fails

Tags: windows

I have installed many of our custom written services on windows boxes (does not matter if XP, Server, Vista).  I always configure to "Restart the Service" on 1st, 2nd and subsequent failures.  But I have never seen this work; the service simply stops (because of an error or something in the code) but does not restart.

I just noticed the "Enable Actions For Stops With Errors" checkbox.  Does this have to be checked in order for the recovery to take affect if the failure was caused by an error?

thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your services are stopping because of an error, that is logged by windows then yes, you need to tick 'Enable Actions For Stops With Errors', otherwise it will not work.

If you do not have this ticked, then it will only restart services that have stopped for legitimate or unknown reasons.

[image]

You can also do it with commandline:

```perl
 sc.exe failureflag [MyService] 1
```

Comment: Thanks - I kind of figured that.  But I would have thought "Error" would be the same thing as a "failure", and hence the service should have started without checking the box.

Comment: It does seem a little odd I agree, as most of the reasons a service would fail you would think would be an error.

Comment: No recovery action is ever to be triggered on services that have stopped for "legitimate" reasons. This answer still makes confusion upon "stop" and "failure" terms.

Comment: Whomever at Microsoft that penned this language should be endlessly flogged for their incompetence.

Comment: Huh? Without it ticked it restarts for legit/unknown reasons ... you mean legit/unknown errors? With it ticked, it restarts for errors that are logged by windows. Are these illegitimated and/or known errors? These terms clarify nothing for me.

Comment: @steve it is based on the exit code of the service, if the exit code is >0 it will not restart unless this is ticked.

Comment: Is this how it works: Regardless of this checkbox, the server process will restart if it crashes; no result code. But if it exits (normally), but with status code, then the check comes into play; causing restart if the code indicates error (non zero).

Comment: If a service exists without an exit code, or with a 0 exit code then this is not a crash as far as Windows is concerned, it has just exited, and it will restart. If the exit code is >0 then this indicates it stopped with an error and will not be restarted without this tick box being checked.

Answer (score 25):

The "Enable actions for stops with errors" checkbox was introduced with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, providing a single, embarrassing line of [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx):

> Select **Enable actions for stops with errors** in order to trigger the
>   recovery actions that the service stopped with an error.

The **SC.exe** program was also updated to provide a new command: `failureflag`. The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742011(v=ws.10).aspx) shows a bad example and doesn't really apply to Windows Server 2003, but tells us that the command:

> Specifies whether recovery actions will be triggered when a service
>   stops as the result of an error.

So, the checkbox and `sc failureflag` are used to set the same flag.
Let's type `sc failureflag` in the command prompt, we finally get a quite decent description:

> Changes the failure actions flag setting of a service. If this setting
>   is 0 (default), the Service Control Manager (SCM) enables configured
>   failure actions on the service only if the service process terminates
>   with the service in a state other than SERVICE_STOPPED. If this
>   setting is 1, the SCM enables configured failure actions on the
>   service if the service enters the SERVICE_STOPPED state with a Win32
>   exit code other than 0 in addition to the service process termination
>   as above. This setting is ignored if the service does not have any
>   failure actions configured.

A similar description can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685937(v=vs.85).aspx).
So, the correct answer to the original question is: the configured recovery actions always take effect when your service doesn't terminate in the SERVICE_STOPPED state.
"Enable actions for stops with errors" must be checked if you need to enable the recovery actions also when your service enters the SERVICE_STOPPED state, provided that the exit code is **not 0** (error).

Comment: Kudos for a very helpful answer!

Comment: This answer is 1000% better than the accepted answer.